# Tkinter Python 3, How to remove greyish white strip on a tkinter.messagebox window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkmessagebox

I am making a tkinter app in Python 3. Whenever I make a `tkmessage` box, for example with `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo()`, the whole bottom part of the window (the part where the button is located) including the button appears as a greyish white strip. However, the body of the window where the message appears is a nice white. I was wondering how I could fix this, as I would like to make the background completely white like the body.

Comment: what OS are you seeing this on?

Comment: @BryanOakley I see it on Windows 10

Comment: you can always create own messagebox from scratch.

Comment: @furas if no one finds a way to resolve it I'll do that